# iOS - Cant change view origin

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

I am plowing through the Big Nerd Ranch Guide 4th Edition, but in the chapter dealing with Views and View Hierarchy I am experiencing some problems with view origins.

I have added a custom subview to my view controller and overwritten the drawRect to draw a bunch of circles in the middle of the screen, however, the origin of the circles won't change and they all get stuck up in the left corner, and I have no idea why. I have literally just copied the code from the book, where it seems to work just fine.

This is my drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;

    //Figure out the center of the bounds rectangle
    CGPoint center;
    center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width/2.0;
    center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height/2.0;

    //The largest circle will circumscribe the view
    float maxRadius = hypotf(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)/2.0;

    UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];

    //Loops and create multiple circles with different radii
    for (float currentRadius = maxRadius; currentRadius > 0 ; currentRadius -= 20) {
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x +currentRadius, center.y)];
        [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:currentRadius startAngle:0.0 endAngle:M_PI*2.0    clockwise:YES];
    }

    path.lineWidth = 10;
    [self.circleColor setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}
```

And here is the outcome. A bunch of circles NOT in the center of the screen...

[image]

Comment: Try `CGRectGetMidX(rect)` and `CGRectGetMidY(rect)` for creating the center CGPoint.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a few things.

1. Find out where your view's origin is by creating another view, smaller, bright blue or anything, and say centerView.center = biggerView.center. Of course, hook it up.
2. Depending on your results, move your frames/views appropriately.
3. Is autolayout working? Is it defined right? Try turning it off for this one.
4. Try using self.center.x and y instead of making another center.x/y.
5. Actually do this first. Log or breakpoint bounds and make sure it's not 0 for width. You can print it with NSStringFromCGRect()

Comment: It definitely seems like #5 to me. If I see an equation like `0 = x + w/2` and I know that `x` is `0` then it's pretty clear to me that `w` is also `0`.

Comment: this is no answer - yet - but id also go with 5.